# Dealing with a nested ng-repeat with AngularJS. Cannot get a button with ng-click to click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I apologize but I'm very new to Angular and I'm even sure how to ask the question. My end goal is to make a bike shop "website" where the user can edit the bikes. Furthermore, they can add accessories to the bikes. Currently everything works unless I'm trying to add in new accessories.

If you look at the button with ng-click="store.appendAcc()" and try to click, it won't work on a NEW bike. It only works if I manually add in the bike information into self.products or if I get rid of the ng-repeat in the div with class "add-parts". I appreciate the help!

html:

```
<div class="name">

    <form>

        <div ng-show="store.showPromo" class="showing">
            <div class="promo-showing" ng-repeat="bike in store.products">
                <div class="promo-bikes">
                    <p>{{bike.name}}</p>
                    <p>{{bike.price}}</p>
                    <div ng-repeat="accessory in bike.accessories" class="accesories">
                        <p>{{accessory.name}}</p>
                        <p>{{accessory.price}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button ng-click="store.switchToEdit()">Edit</button>   
        </div>

        <div ng-show="!store.showPromo" class="editing">
            <div ng-repeat="bike in store.products">
                <input ng-model="bike.name">
                <input ng-model="bike.price">
                <button ng-click="store.appendAcc()">add accessories</button>
                <div ng-show="store.showAcc" ng-repeat="accessory in bike.accessories" class="add-parts">
                    <input class="accessory-input" ng-model="accessory.name">
                    <input class="accessory-input" ng-model="accessory.price">
                    <button ng-click="store.hideAcc()">submit accessories</button>
                </div>      
            </div>  
            <button ng-click="store.newBike()" type="submit">Create New</button>
            <button ng-click="store.switchToPromo()">See Promo Screen</button>
        </div>      

    </form>



</div>
```

js:

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module('bike', []);

    app.controller('storeCtrl', function() {

        var self = this;

        self.showPromo;
        self.showAcc;

        self.products = [
        {
            name: 'bike',
            price: '$$$',
            accessories: [{
                name: 'handles',
                price: 99
            }, {
                name: 'seat',
                price: 60
            }]
        }
        ];

        self.newBike = function(named, priced, partName, partPrice) {
            self.products.push({
                name: named || 'edit bike',
                price: priced || 'edit price',
            });
        }

        self.switchToPromo = function () {
            self.showPromo = 'on';
            // for (var i = self.parts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            //  console.log(self.parts[i])
            //  document.querySelector('.promo-bikes').appendChild(self.parts[i])
            // };
        }

        self.switchToEdit = function () {
            self.showPromo = undefined;
        }

        self.appendAcc = function () {
            self.showAcc = 'on';
        }

        self.hideAcc = function (named, priced) {
            self.showAcc = undefined;
        }

    })

})();
```

Comment: Try $parent.appendAcc()

Comment: Where are you setting ng-controller?

Comment: I actually don't get what is your code supposed to do, check this out http://plnkr.co/edit/EEZ7csDj2KKRU1sgwFMs?p=info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's probably that accessories is undefined when you create a new bike, so there is nothing to "repeat" in the ng-repeat.  I suggest initializing a new bike with

```
self.newBike = function(named, priced, partName, partPrice) {
        self.products.push({
            name: named || 'edit bike',
            price: priced || 'edit price',
            accessories: [{
                name:  partName || 'add part',
                price: partPrice || 'add price'
            }]
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen anyone use `this` the way you are in Angular. I always use `$scope` but you must inject it into your controller. Any properties you add to `$scope` are available in the view.

```
app.controller('storeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope)
{
    $scope.showPromo = false;
    $scope.showAcc = false;

    ...

    $scope.appendAcc = function () {
        $scope.showAcc = 'on';
    }
}
```

You will also need to remove the `store` prefix from your view and reference properties off of `$scope` directly like this:

```
<div ng-show="!showPromo" class="editing">
    <div ng-repeat="bike in products">
        <input ng-model="bike.name">
        <input ng-model="bike.price">
        <button ng-click="appendAcc()">add accessories</button>
        <div ng-show="showAcc" ng-repeat="accessory in bike.accessories" class="add-parts">
            <input class="accessory-input" ng-model="accessory.name">
            <input class="accessory-input" ng-model="accessory.price">
            <button ng-click="hideAcc()">submit accessories</button>
        </div>      
    </div>  
    <button ng-click="newBike()" type="submit">Create New</button>
    <button ng-click="switchToPromo()">See Promo Screen</button>
</div>
```

Also, without seeing the rest of your code, I'm not sure why you have your code wrapped in a closure. I don't believe that is necessary, and could cause issues.

Comment: there are more than one way to pass information to angular controller and one of them is controller as, that way you can write it like this " var self = this;" this is not the problem, he can use multiple levels of controllers. actually his way is better

Comment: The pattern the OP is probably using is "controllerAs" syntax.  Using that pattern, you don't have to inject $scope.

Comment: Thanks @OQX and Joe ... I had no idea!